# Как некоторые сайты определяют твое присутствие ВКонтакте?

Tags: php, вконтакте

Особенно часто это можно видеть при оставлении коментов. Шаришь допустим по статейке, какой-нить, а там внизу твоя ава из ВК. Мне надо что-то подобное. А вообще идея такая - даю чуваку ссылку на свой скрипт. Он по ней идет, а скрипт в логи пишет id вконтакте или может имя, того кто перешел по ней. Как такое сделать на PHP и на сколько это реально. Мой уровень в кодинге на PHP начинающий. Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Надо как-то прикрутить в скрипт ВКонтакте API? А можно попросить у браузера куки от ВК?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторизация в вконтакте может произойти только со страницы вконтакте. А определение возможно происходит через различные oauth запросы. Смотрите vk api.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [виджетов ВК](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?o=-1&p=Comments). Это то, что вы имели в виду?

Answer (score 0):

> А можно попросить у браузера куки от ВК?

нельзя конечно

Идея провальная конечно, если в самом вк нет какойнить уязвимости потипу xss.